# Is there a way to print all methods of an object?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to print all methods of an object in JavaScript?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Sure:

```
function getMethods(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for (var id in obj) {
    try {
      if (typeof(obj[id]) == "function") {
        result.push(id + ": " + obj[id].toString());
      }
    } catch (err) {
      result.push(id + ": inaccessible");
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Using it:

```
alert(getMethods(document).join("\n"));
```

Comment: the try/catch is a good approach. There are some property/methods in IE that will error out on access.

Comment: Yeah, I think there are some in Firefox as well.

Comment: Note that it doesn't work on some built-in objects like Date:
`var a = new Date(); console.log(typeof a, getMethods(a));`

Returns:

`object []`.

Comment: For `Date`, this worked for me : `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date.prototype)`

Answer (score 25):

If you just want to look what is inside an object, you can print all object's keys. Some of them can be variables, some - methods.

The method is not very accurate, however it's really quick:

```
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```

Comment: Why does `Object.keys(new Date());` give me an empty array?

Comment: @old-geezer This returns all date methods,

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date.prototype).join("\n")`

Answer (score 6):

Here is an `ES6` sample.

```
// Get the Object's methods names:
function getMethodsNames(obj = this) {
    return Object.keys(obj)
        .filter((key) => typeof obj[key] === 'function');
}

// Get the Object's methods (functions):
function getMethods(obj = this) {
    return Object.keys(obj)
        .filter((key) => typeof obj[key] === 'function')
        .map((key) => obj[key]);
}
```

`obj = this` is an ES6 default parameter, you can pass in an Object or it will default to `this`.

`Object.keys` returns an Array of the `Object`'s own enumerable properties.
Over the `window` Object it will return `[..., 'localStorage', ...'location']`.

`(param) => ...` is an ES6 arrow function, it's a shorthand for

```
function(param) {
    return ...
}
```

with an implicit return.

`Array.filter` creates a new array with all elements that pass the test (`typeof obj[key] === 'function'`).

`Array.map` creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array (return `obj[key]`).

Comment: This is useful! One correction: inside the functions `obj` should be used instead of `this`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a gander at this code:-

```
function writeLn(s)
{
    //your code to write a line to stdout
    WScript.Echo(s)
}

function Base() {}
Base.prototype.methodA = function() {}
Base.prototype.attribA = "hello"

var derived = new Base()
derived.methodB = function() {}
derived.attribB = "world";

function getMethods(obj)
{
    var retVal = {}

    for (var candidate in obj)
    {
        if (typeof(obj[candidate]) == "function")
            retVal[candidate] = {func: obj[candidate], inherited: !obj.hasOwnProperty(candidate)}
    }
    return retVal
}

var result = getMethods(derived)
for (var name in result)
{
    writeLn(name + " is " + (result[name].inherited ? "" : "not") + " inherited")
}
```

The getMethod function returns the set of methods along with whether the method is one that has been inherited from a prototype.

Note that if you intend to use this on objects that are supplied from the context such as browser/DOM object then it won't work IE.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/looping.shtml):

Example 1: This example writes out all the properties of the "navigator" object, plus their values:

```
for (var myprop in navigator){
 document.write(myprop+": "+navigator[myprop]+"<br>")
}
```

Just replace 'navigator' with whatever object you are interested in and you should be good to go.

As mentioned by Anthony in the comments section - This returns all attributes not just methods as the question asked for.

Oops!  That'll teach me to try and answer a question in a language I don't know.  Still, I think the code is useful - just not what was required.

Comment: This returns all attributes not just methods as the question asked for.  On IE it only returns some of the properties and none of the methods.

Answer (score 1):

Since methods in JavaScript are just properties that are functions, the for..in loop will enumerate them with an exception - it won't enumerate built-in methods. As far as I know, there is no way to enumerate built-in methods. And you can't declare your own methods or properties on an object that aren't enumerable this way.