# result of expression undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am using this function for playing some embedded wav files.

```
function playnote(note) {
  document.embeds[note].play();
}
```

I am getting result of expression undefined is not a function after I click on the button that calls this function

I should be using "Play" and it would work!! :)

Comment: Can you post the code that calls this function?

Comment: <embed src=MUSIC FILE URL hidden=true autostart=false>

<a href="#" onClick="playnote(0)" > 
<img src=IMAGE URL border="0" align = top> </a>

Answer (score 2):

Paste this at the beginning of `playnote()`. If you use Firebug, `console.debug` is a better replacement of `alert`.

```
alert(document.embeds);
alert(document.embeds[note]);
```

I bet the second alert will yield `undefined`. And JavaScript can't invoke methods on `undefined`. Apparently `embeds` array/object does not contain index/field for `note`.

Comment: can you explan why its happening and how these two statements will solve it ?

Comment: These statements are suppose to help you diagnose the problem. Based on the code snippets you've added (please edit your original question and put them there), looks like you either don't have `embeds` variables defined anywhere, it doesn't have an element at index `0` or - the element at index `0` does not have `play()` method.

Comment: yes. you are correct. second alert yield undefinied. how can I defined a set of music files in an array, if embed doesn't contain a field ?

Comment: actually, it worked. I was just using "play" when I should be using "Play"....I am such a novice

Answer (score 0):

The fragment of code: `document.embeds[note]` probably resolves to nothing. It may be that this portion of the page has not loaded or the html is incorrectly formed.

It would help to post the html for this page.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Displaying Times and Dates </title>
</head>



<body> <h1> My music </h1>
<p>




<script language="JavaScript" >
function playnote(x) {
document.embeds[x].play();
}
</script>

<embed src="C0.wav" hidden=true autostart=false>
<embed src="Cs0.wav" hidden=true autostart=false>





<a href="#" onClick="playnote(0)" > 
<img src="whitekey.gif" border="0" align = top> </a>
<a href="#" onClick="playnote(1)" > 
<img src="blackkey.gif" border="0" align = top> </a>



</body>
</html>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152483/is-there-a-way-to-print-all-methods-of-an-object-in-javascript might be handy too