# Stringify an object with function expressions - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, function, expression, stringify

Is it possible? I need to stringify js object with function expressions with all value types on other fields to be not changed.

Example:

I have such javascript object -

```
var obj = {
    propText: "some text",
    propBool: true,
    propNum: 12345,
    method: function () {
       // some logic here
    }
};
```

Unfortunately if I'll use `JSON.stringify(obj);` it will return string without `method`..

Then I can use replacer function like this:

```
JSON.stringify(obj, function (key, val) {
  if (typeof val === 'function') {
    return '' + val;
  }
  return val;
});
```

which will bring me string with functions like strings inside like `"function () { ... }"`..

Another option I've tried is more complex but result is still a bit not acceptable - use custom `stringify` function that will wrap `JSON.stringify` and then replace placeholders in strings

```
var stringify = function (obj, prop) {
  var placeholder = '____PLACEHOLDER____';
  var fns = [];
  var json = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'function') {
      fns.push(value);
      return placeholder;
    }
    return value;
  });
  json = json.replace(new RegExp('"' + placeholder + '"', 'g'), function(_) {
    return fns.shift();
  });
  return json;
};
```

but this function is not acceptable for example if you pass another values:

```
JSON.stringify(22); // outputs 22 typeof number
stringify(22); // outputs 22 typeof function because of .replace() :(
```

I want my stringified object to look like:

```
'{
    "propText": "some text",
    "propBool": true,
    "propNum": 12345,
    "method": function () { ... }
}'
```

Comment: What do you want the functions to look like in the stringified version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to print all methods of an object in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152483/is-there-a-way-to-print-all-methods-of-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Take a look at this : http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/07/json-serialize-and-deserialize.html

Comment: @jfriend00 I've updated the question with how it should look like

Comment: The example for what you said you want it to look like isn't a valid javascript string because you're using double quotes both as end delimiters and within the string.

Comment: What do you need this for? Notice that not in all JS implementations you can stringify functions at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 it was just a typo