# Get all methods of any object?

Tags: javascript

In python word there are dir() function which

> return a list of valid attributes for that object

In JS words I found:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames

Object.keys
```

but they don't show ALL attributes:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames([])
[ 'length' ]
```

How to get list of all attributes and methods as

```
concat, entries, every, find....
```

for Array() for example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to print all methods of an object in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152483/is-there-a-way-to-print-all-methods-of-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @ErikBrodyDreyer—that question is not really a duplicate, since in 2008 there was no method to get non–enumerable property names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype)`

The reason why trying to get the values the way you posted does not work, is because you are requesting the property names for a single **instance** of the `Array` object. For a number of reasons, each instance will only have property values that are **unique** to that instance. Since the values found in `Array.prototype` are not unique to a specific instance -- which makes sense, not all arrays are going to share the same value for `length` -- they are shared/inherited for all instances of `Array`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) with [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) in order to traverse the prototype chain and collect all own properties on each object.

```js
var result = []
var obj = []
do {
  result.push(...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj))
} while ((obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)))

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = result.join("\n")
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

This handles all properties irrespective of whether or not they're inherited or enumerable. This does not include `Symbol` properties however. To include those, you can use [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols).

```
var result = []
var obj = []
do {
  result.push(...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj), ...Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj))
} while ((obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)))
```

Comment: Since the OP wants methods, there should be a filter for Function objects (or at least callable objects).

Comment: @RobG: Maybe. The OP mentions *"attributes and methods"*, so I'm not sure exactly how much or little should be included.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

> The **`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`** method returns an array of all properties (enumerable or not) found directly upon a given object.

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will allow you to pull all the keys and functions from a particular instance of an object (ignoring the unwanted ones):

```js
const ROOT_PROTOTYPE = Object.getPrototypeOf({});

function getAllKeys(object) {
    // do not add the keys of the root prototype object
    if (object === ROOT_PROTOTYPE) {
        return [];
    }

    const names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object);

    // remove the default constructor for each prototype
    if (names[0] === 'constructor') {
        names.shift();
    }

    // iterate through all the prototypes of this object, until it gets to the root object.
    return names.concat(getAllKeys(Object.getPrototypeOf(object)));
}
```