# unable to get methods of an object in javascript / reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with ReactJS, but I think my question might be a general javascript question.  I have two classes `Url` and `QueryVars`.  I want `Url` to be able to call all the methods of `QueryVars`, as if I extended `Url` from `QueryVars`.  So I did something like this:

```
export default class Url {

  constructor()
  {
    this.queryVars = new QueryVars();

    console.log(this.queryVars);
    for(let x in this.queryVars)
    {
      console.log(x); // this never gets fired
      if(typeof this.queryVars[x] == "function")
      {
        this[x] = this.queryVars[x].bind(this.queryVars);
      }
    }
  }
}

default class QueryVars {

  init()
  {
    /* do something */
  }
  getQS(key)
  {
    /* do something */
  }
  getPage(key)
  {
    /* do something */
  }
}
```

The thing is that the `console.log(x)` does not get fired.  I'm unable to retrieve the methods of `this.queryVars`.   What am I doing wrong here?

Eventually, I want to assign a few more objects into the `Url.constructor` and bind more methods of those objects, so that it seems like I'm implementing multiple inheritance, or composing a new class out of other classes.  So that I can:

```
do url.getQS() instead of url.queryVars.getQS()
do url.getIP() instead of url.ip.getIP()
etc...
```

My code above was based on what I learned in this question here:
[Is there a way to print all methods of an object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152483/is-there-a-way-to-print-all-methods-of-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: i think you want a mixin? http://justinfagnani.com/2015/12/21/real-mixins-with-javascript-classes/

Comment: @mr.void Ooohhh yeah, that's what I'm trying to achieve.  Ok, will need some time to read that article, because it doesn't sound like it's as easy to achieve as what I posted in my question.

Comment: in a simple cause you could just do this: Object.assign(obj1, obj2);

Comment: I'm not sure of a good pattern, but the reason your code isn't working is because: 1. class methods are not defined on the object, but on the class prototype and 2. methods are not enumerable, so they don't show up in `for…in`. You could have to do something like `for(let x of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(this.queryVars)))` to enumerate them.